# Append value to multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, append

I have a multidimensional array in PHP that appears as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [background] => https://example.com/image.jpg
        [description] => Example text
        [url] => https://example.com
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [background] => https://example.com/image.jpg
        [description] => Example text
        [url] => https://example.com
    )
)
```

I would like to loop through this array and append the same parameter to both `url` keys. I tried doing this through a function with a double foreach loop and was able to append the parameter successfully, but I'm having trouble returning an array with the updated values.

Here is what I've tried:

**Call**

```
$array = append_field($array, 'url', '?parameter=test');
```

**Function**

```
function append_field($array, $field, $parameter)
{
    foreach ($array as $inner_array) :
        foreach ($inner_array as $key => $append) :
            if ($key == $field) :
                $append .= $parameter;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the array values as references in both foreach loops to be able to write to them. Otherwise you are iterating over copies of your values.

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

```
function append_field($array, $field, $parameter)
{
    foreach ($array as &$inner_array) :
        foreach ($inner_array as $key => &$append) :
            if ($key == $field) :
                $append .= $parameter;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    return $array;
}
```

But you could also do it without references, this time by writing to the full array path including both keys :

```
function append_field($array, $field, $parameter)
{
    foreach ($array as $i => $inner_array) :
        foreach ($inner_array as $key => $append) :
            if ($key == $field) :
                $array[$i][$key] .= $parameter;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change this line

```
$append .= $parameter;
```

to this

```
$inner_array[$key] = $append.$parameter
```

and `foreach ($array as $inner_array):` to `foreach ($array as &$inner_array) :`

Answer (score 2):

Some more way, to achieve same result, for example using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        'background'=>'https://example.com/image.jpg',
        'description'=>'Example text',
        'url'=>'https://example.com'
    ),
    array(
        'background'=>'https://example.com/image.jpg',
        'description'=>'Example text',
        'url'=>'https://example.com'
    ),

);

$append = array('url'=>'?parameter=test');
print_r( 
    array_map(function($item) use ($append) {foreach($append as $k => $v){ if(isset($item[$k]))$item[$k].=$v;}return $item;}, $arr )
);


?>
```

Output:

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [background] => https://example.com/image.jpg
            [description] => Example text
            [url] => https://example.com?parameter=test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [background] => https://example.com/image.jpg
            [description] => Example text
            [url] => https://example.com?parameter=test
        )

)
```